# Dotnet how to serialize binary data for mongo

Tags: asp.net, .net, mongodb, bson

I've got file data that I need to save in mongo in a dotnet application. The data needs to be serialized to mongo and then deserialized in a worker thread as (ideally) the same object.
I've been finding the tooling a little esoteric (maybe I don't know the right places to look yet).
Given the following object

```
public class File {
  public IEnumerable<byte> Data { get; set; }
  public string C { get; set; }
  public string D { get; set; }
}

public class X {
  public IEnumerable<File> Files { get; set; }
  public string A { get; set; }
  public string B { get; set; }
}

...

var toInsert = new X {
 A = "a", B = "b", Files = new []{ new File { Data = <byte array>, C ="c", D = "d" }
}
```

When I insert `toInsert` into mongo, without any custom serialization, it ends up like

```
{
  a: "a", 
  b: "b", 
  files: [
    {
      c: "c",
      d: "d",
      data: <binary>

    }
  ]
}
```

Which seems fine enough. When I try to pull the object out of mongo (again, without any custom serialization) I get the following error

> Cannot deserialize a 'List' from BsonType 'Binary'.

Now, I've tried a *lot* of different things here - enough that I'm not going to go through the list, but this behavior I found peculiar. The client knows to turn an array of `byte` into a `Binary` Bson object but it has no idea how to get it back out?

The question is: what is the idiomatic dotnet / mongo way of serializing bytes to a document and reading them back out?